# Domino Designer doesn't initialize

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

When I launch Domino Designer, I don't see any databases listed.  When I open DD for a specific database, I get the same thing.  My Notes client still works fine.

Is my DD behavior due to me no longer hitting a live Domino server?  (My user license is good until 2024).

[image]

UPDATE: I noticed the errors below under **Problems**:

[image]

Comment: Try Window - Reset perspective

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten just tried it.  It did not resolve my issue, unfortunately.

Comment: What about Window - Open Perspective - Domino Designer (or e.g. XPages)?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten that doesn't solve it either.  I did notice some error messages under Problems.  I added a screen shot above.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Menu "Window --> Show Eclipse Views --> Applications" will show you selected databases in "Applications" tab in Domino Designer.

Comment: I don't see that option.  I have DD 9.0.1

Comment: It is in Domino Designer **Eclipse based Standard** Client, in 9.0.1 too.

Comment: Do you see *Window / Show Eclipse Views*? You might find *Applications* in */ Other... / Domino Designer*

Comment: I don't have a menu option for "Applications".

Comment: Do you see menu *Window / Show Eclipse Views*?

Comment: Yes.  I don't see "Applications" under that menu.

Comment: That's weird. I'd reinstall Notes Client completely...

Answer (score 0):

Using the repair/modify options did not work.  The solution was to completely uninstall Notes/Domino Designer/Admin and reinstall.